# Hi.I am new to android, and I want to achieve below image slide view In which next and preview image should appear a bit

Tags: android

I am new to android, and I want to achieve below image slide view in which next and preview image should appear a bit. I am using App-intro library. I have stored images in local . I tried with App-intro library but I'm unable to achieve the result. Thanks in Advance.[Image slide with next and previous image preview(a bit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQHWt.jpg)

Comment: You need `ViewPager` or (horizontal) `RecyclerView` with `LinearSnapHelper`

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution to achieve what you want.

```
viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);

// set padding manually, the more you set the padding the more you see of prev & next page
viewPager.setPadding(40, 0, 40, 0);

// sets a margin b/w individual pages to ensure that there is a gap b/w them
viewPager.setPageMargin(20);
```

Whatever padding you want on top and bottom specify in xml file

```
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:paddingBottom="50dp"
```

Comment: Thank You :) You saved my day . is it possible with fragment?